# C++ code passes all test cases and stress testing, but fails online test

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, compiler-errors

I'm a C++ noob, so forgive me if this is a really dumb question. This is a question that I had to code for:

**Problem Description:**

**Task.** Given  points on a plane, find the smallest distance between a pair of two (different) points.

**Input Format.** The first line contains the number  of points. Each of the following  lines defines a point (, ).

**Constraints.** 2 ≤  ≤ 10^5; −10^9 ≤ ,  ≤ 10^9 are integers.

**Output Format.** Output the minimum distance. The absolute value of the difference between the answer
of your program and the optimal value should be at most 10^−3

Input:

2

0 0

3 4

Output:

5.0

(This is a problem from the UC San Diego University DSA course on Coursera).

Stress testing works, and it shows no error, but the Coursera checker throws this output: " Unknown Signal 11". Now the guidelines say "Unknown signal 6 (or 7, or 8, or 11, or some other). This happens when your program crashes. It can be because of a division by zero, accessing memory outside of the array bounds, using
uninitialized variables, overly deep recursion that triggers a stack overflow, sorting with a contradictory
comparator, removing elements from an empty data structure, trying to allocate too much memory,
and many other reasons."

Needless to say, that didn't narrow too much down for me. Could someone please tell me where my code fails? Trying to debug is driving me crazy, especially since I have no idea where it is failing. (And the block of if statements is there only because I thought that was where it was causing problems, but apparently not>)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::pair;
using std::min;
using namespace std;

struct Point {

  long long x;
  long long y;
};

bool comparex(Point a, Point b) {

  if (a.x <= b.x) return true;
  else return false;
}

bool comparey(Point a, Point b) {

  if (a.y <= b.y) return true;
  else return false;
}

double dist(Point a, Point b) {

  double res = 0;
  res = sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));

  return res;
}


double merge(vector<Point> p, int l, int mid, int r, double d) {
  //cout << "Here1" << endl;

  vector<Point> strip;
  //cout << "here2" << endl;
  int i = 1;

  while (((double)p[mid].x - p[mid - i].x) <= d && (mid - i) >= l) {

    strip.push_back(p[mid - i]);

    i++;
  }
  //cout << "here3" << endl;

  i = 1;

  while (((double)p[mid + i].x - p[mid].x) <= d && (mid + i) <= r) {
    //cout << "i " << i << endl;
    strip.push_back(p[mid + i]);

    i++;
  }
  //cout << "here4" << endl;
  strip.push_back(p[mid]);
  //cout << "here5" << endl;


  sort(strip.begin(), strip.end(), comparey);

  /*for (int j = 0; j < strip.size(); j++) {

    cout << strip[j].x << " " << strip[j].y << endl;
  }*/

  double minimum = d;

  for (size_t j = 0; j < strip.size(); j++) {

    if (j + 1 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 1]));}
    if (j + 2 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 2]));}
    if (j + 3 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 3]));}
    if (j + 4 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 4]));}
    if (j + 5 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 5]));}
    if (j + 6 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 6]));}
    if (j + 7 < strip.size()) {minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(strip[j], strip[j + 7]));}

  }


  return minimum;


}

double minimal_distance(vector<Point> p, int l, int r) {
  //write your code here
  if (l + 1 == r) {
    return dist(p[l], p[r]);
  }

  else if (l + 2 == r) {
    return std::min({dist(p[l], p[l + 1]), dist(p[l], p[l + 2]), dist(p[l + 1], p[l + 2])});
  }


  else {

    sort(p.begin(), p.end(), comparex);

    int mid = (l + r) / 2;

    //cout << " l " << l << " r " << r << " mid " << mid << endl;

    double d = std::min(minimal_distance(p, l, mid), minimal_distance(p, mid + 1, r));

    //cout << "left " << minimal_distance(p, l, mid) << " right" << minimal_distance(p, mid + 1, r) << endl;

    double d1 = merge(p, l , mid, r, d);


    return std::min(d, d1);



  }
}

double naive(vector<Point> p, int l, int r) {


  double minimum = dist(p[l], p[r]);
  for (size_t i = l; i <= r; i++) {

    for (size_t j = i + 1; j <= r; j++) {


      minimum = std::min(minimum, dist(p[i], p[j]));
    }
  }
  return minimum;
}

int main() {

  size_t n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<Point> p(n);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> p[i].x >> p[i].y;
  }
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << minimal_distance(p, 0, n - 1) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you are using `using namespace std;` , you don't need all the other `using`s, since everything you put there IS in the std namespace

Comment: Your `comparex` and `comparey` functions are not strict weak orderings, so your sorting has undefined behaviour.

Comment: [Strict weak orderings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) on Wikipedia. In particular, your functions say that any element should be ordered before itself, and that any two elements with the same x (or y) should both be ordered before each other.

Comment: So just `bool comparex(Point a, Point b) { return a.x < b.x; }` should work. Its the `<` part that is important. Your comparison functions should return `false` if given two equal values.

Comment: @molbdnilo That actually resolved the unknown error issue! Thanks! I mean, my code is now exceeding the time limit, but anything's better than that unknown error :)

Comment: @user_9 To prevent TLE, use the algorithm mentioned at the end of the assignment's pdf. [This was my approach at first](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YmAn0uP5m8wkpaUj). If you try you can write better code than this with similar algorithm. The idea remains same to limit time complexity to `O(nlogn)` by divide and conquer. :)

Comment: Also, stress testing didn't show any error. Is it due to the compiler or because the random values in stress test just didn't hit this error?

Comment: Unrelated: @brc-dd `int32_t main()` ...? That's the first time I've seen that :-) You know that an `int` doesn't have to be 32 bits, right? Stick with `int main()`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually that code was pretty old, I had stopped using that long time ago. I had it in one of my repository, so I pulled it and shared it here as comment. I used to write that thinking that one needs to return a 32-bit int, I know I was wrong. I didn't used `int` directly because some times when things go wrong in competitive programming questions due to integer overflow, I used to write `#define int long long` on the top of code, and it used to work mostly... I know none of this was ideal, nor should be used in development. :)

Comment: @user_9 It has nothing to do with the compiler for sure. Another thing: You have commented lines like `cout << "here" << endl;` in your code. You should try using a debugger, that makes the work a lot easier.

Comment: [My fixed solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BS11dLcxY8voFbUs). Please ignore the link sent by me in above comments.